# Best way to render model attribute key names in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, interpolation

I'm writing show and index views to render model objects and instead of hardcoding model attribute title names into the view I'd like to find a better way of rendering these titles and assigning them to their related variables for future rendering use.

Could you advise as to a best practice solution?

Old hardcoded:

```
<tr>
  <td>Company name</td> # Would like to interpolate readable vers of attr key here.
  <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company number</td>
  <td><%= @quote.co_number %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Office postcode</td>
  <td><%= @quote.postcode %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Industry</td>
  <td><%= @quote.industry %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/ruby-on-rails-i18n-form-labels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode the column names but want them to be readable you can make use of ActiveRecord translations

```yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      quote:
        co_name: "Company name"
        co_number: "Company number"
        postcode: "Office postcode"
        industry: "Industry"
```

Use [**`human_attribute_name`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name) to display the localized attribute name

```
<tr>
  <td><%= Quote.human_attribute_name(:co_name) %></td>
  <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
</tr>
```

**NOTE:** Advantage of using this format is you will also get proper names in

```
@quote.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Company name can't be blank", "Company number can't be blank"]
```